# foreach loop with decoded json data

Tags: php, html, json, foreach

I'm trying to get data from a JSON response to be displayed using a `foreach` loop. However if I try that I get this error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

The data I put in the `foreach` loop isn't null or empty, I checked that.

My code:

```
$json = file_get_contents($goodurl);
$the_data = json_decode($json, true);
$count = 0;
foreach($the_data->response as $video)
{
//case show results as text only
//echo $video->title;
$html.= "<p><div class='p2go_title'><a href='". $video->playbackUrl ."' target='_blank'>" . $video->title . "</a></div>";
$html.= "<div class='p2go_contributors'>By: ". $video->contributors ."</div>";
$html.= "<div class='p2go_views'>Views: ". $video->views ."</div></p>";

$count++;
}
return $html;
```

Comment: The second argument for json_decode forces return value to array try `$the_data['response']` or set it to false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$the_data` is array. Try with -

```
foreach($the_data['response'] as $video)
```

`json_decode($json, true);` will return an array. The second parameter is used for this only.

**Update**

The inner elements also be needed to be accesed as array -

```
$html.= "<p><div class='p2go_title'><a href='". $video['playbackUrl'] ."' target='_blank'>" . $video['title'] . "</a></div>";
$html.= "<div class='p2go_contributors'>By: ". $video['contributors'] ."</div>";
$html.= "<div class='p2go_views'>Views: ". $video['views'] ."</div></p>";
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Trying to get property of non-object. And I already had the json_decode($json,true)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are setting `json_decode` to return an array, access it as an `array`, not an `object`.

```
$the_data = json_decode($json, true); // if you set 2nd paramater to true, it will return an array

foreach($the_data['response'] as $video)
{
   $html.= "<p><div class='p2go_title'><a href='". $video['playbackUrl']."' target='_blank'>" . $video['title'] . "</a></div>";
   $html.= "<div class='p2go_contributors'>By: ". $video['contributors'] ."</div>";
   $html.= "<div class='p2go_views'>Views: ". $video['views'] ."</div></p>";

 $count++;
}
```

Comment: Here I get the error: Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: Yup! I already thought so myself. But thanks anyway, you helped a bunch! :D